# Posting two different JSON objects

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-post

I Am Using Spring Boot in which i want a method to get details of person with its land details .
A person can have any number of lands. 
I have created a following method but it is not working

```
@PutMapping("/fl-details/{f}/{l}")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<PersonDetailsDTO> updateDetails(@RequestParam("f") PersonDetailsDTO personDetailsDTO,
    @RequestParam("l") List<LandDetailsDTO> landDetailsDTOS) throws URISyntaxException {
    if (personDetailsDTO.getId() == null || landDetailsDTOS.iterator().next().getId() == null) {
        return createFarmerDetails(personDetailsDTO,landDetailsDTOS);
    }

    PersonDetailsDTO result = personDetailsService.save(personDetailsDTO);

    landDetailsDTOS.stream().forEach(landDetailsService::save);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(ENTITY_PERSON+ENTITY_LAND, personDetailsDTO.getId().toString()))                    
        .body(result);
}
```

I can post person details from

```
@ResponseBody PersonDetailsDTO personDetailsDTO
```

but i am getting confused in post both of these.

Could anyone tell me how could i post two different Kind Of JSON objects in Spring Boot API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `@RequestParam` cannot be deserialised to a `PersonDetailsDTO` or `LandDetailsDTO` (unless you implement a custom converter) so in order to pass a complex object (whether it is of type `PersonDetailsDTO` or type `LandDetailsDTO`) you must use `@ResponseBody`.

And since a controller method can only have one `@ResponseBody` you'll have to pass in a composite object i.e. one which could contain either a `PersonDetailsDTO` or a `LandDetailsDTO`. For example:

```
class CompositeDto {
    private PersonDetailsDTO personDetails;
    private List<LandDetailsDTO> landDetails
}
```

And then interrogate this inside your controller method, for example:

```
if (compositeDto.containsPersonDetails()) {
    // ...
} else if (compositeDto.containsLandDetails()) {
    // ...
}
```